# Algebras Morita equivalent with the Weyl Algebra and its smash products with a finite group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-operators

My question os motivated, naturally, by the problem of classifying symplectic reflection algebras up to Morita equivalence (a classical reference for rational Cherednik algebras is **Y. Berest, P. Etingof, V. Ginzburg**, *"Morita equivalence of Cherednik algebras"*, **MR2034924**; the most up do date work in this subject I know of is **I. Losev**, *Derived equivalences for Symplectic reflection algebras*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05144);

and also the problem of understading rings of differential operators on irreducilbe affine complex varieties $X$ up to Morita equivalence (a nice discussion of this lovely problem in the intersection of ring theory and algebraic geometry can be found in **Y. Berest, G. Wilson**, *"Differential isomorphism and equivalence of algebraic varieties"*, **MR2079372**)

Given that, my questions are:

**(Question 1):** What are the more general known conditions on a symplectic reflection algebra $H_{1,c}(V,\Gamma)$ that imples it is Morita equivalent to $\mathcal{D}(V) \rtimes \Gamma$?

**(Question 2):** What are the recent developments made in the study of equivalence of rings of differential operators up to Morita equivalence (and in particular Morita equivalent to the Weyl algebra) since **Berest, Wilson [op. cit.]**?

**(Question 3):** Etingof in *"Cherednik and Hecke algebras of varieties with a finite group action"*, **MR3734656**, introduces more general versions of rational Cherednik algebras and discuss the possibility of extending the results in **Y. Berest, O. Chalykh**, *Quasi-invariants of complex reflection groups* ,**MR 2801407**, in this setting. So, being optmistic, one hipothetically could obtain results similar as those discussed in **Berest, Etingof, Ginzburg [op. cit]** regarding Morita equivalence of these generalized rational Cherednik algebras with smash products of rings with differential operatos with a finite groups. Has this line of inquiry lead to results relevant to this discussion so far?

**(Question 4):** This is totally unrelated to the previous questions. It is more of a very open question in ring theory: are there interesting simple Noetherian algebras, coming from another areas than those above, which are Morita equivalent to a Weyl algebra or a smash product of it with a finite group?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know much on recent developments related to the first three questions asked. However, i know of some old results related mainly to the fourth question:

If $A_1$ is the Weyl algebra over an alg closed field of zero char, with the two generators denoted $p,q$ and $I$ is a non-zero, right ideal, then $M_2(End_{A_1}(I))\cong M_2(A_1)$ and $A_1$ is Morita equivalent to $End_{A_1}(I)$. Furthermore, these algebras are not generally isomorphic: Pick for example $I=p^2A_1+(pq+1)A_1$. Its endomorphism ring is isomorphic to $\{x\in Q|xI\subseteq I\}$, where $Q$ is the quotient division ring of $A_1$. This is not isomorphic to $A_1$ but it is Morita equivalent to it. If you are interested in this example, this is presented in [An example of a ring Morita equivalent to the Weyl algebra $A_1$, S.P. Smith, J. of Alg, 73, 552 (1981)](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X04140/1-s2.0-0021869381903343/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKn%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCIQCU7nuDMGJ03UKrn5bQrthYdY9hqLxlNx5tfxfO7EbRBQIgFagWGmwJ71Qv7bAnEsDHHALo6qpRUn4FPLCvY2ne9jcqtAMIYhADGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDFKgeWvyvPssCMQ6SiqRAx%2B2ySUd25MQ13h1NOZJz%2BiOoZMGkRDGyAwW%2BIhDAg%2Bem5WfW%2BAVK434RJCrRSlzp6SvFfIx%2BSTuD%2FHe3AEhfZkPdh8YbvNF%2B56FFwa1XljMofFME%2Bbc7rHi1iSzg84O0R%2BufKU4obH7SLyb0hJjO817UZc1PkuEO%2Bpk7lpLfO5MeTAtJuomSWnJ%2B0SNoMSEd4Z8h2lpK%2BpBaNMB8gesJI5MXpbAe2zuexRzx1lKvkMJVY%2BBJukf2qFWLWOlA2GhAmilN86yMVVqQ2DHNkDv%2BARtjXu%2BAiz2EUXAsuNLn6azAEsUxaiy907Zic9Ez6ghKrOvzawgXvyhlnacS2B2r7VOo9YgM7onx6aoJyPO7iQV8E2jgCLlUXwPm5vjmzrfzOWyJAat8EmdLIBXLUvyACjmGYCPve5kXU4Wih82m6gYCRXMUwlmuty16QumyovDsy3uvrawQXRSfwEbjprvjYH%2B%2FhkDHtQmtk%2BdA%2Fdz6IefFrkVKwjkx%2BDZvtVRk8vC3k6PKevucS3EkAWKINkfmhnLMMzU4fgFOusBbhF7qZyMmrNn23uaL3ffpBztNFUag8ksrp8qbiaJ6qFyVjigmFn2BWYjugzBSoyA5qixy6pJ0gj41ZgSZVXw0h3fQL9vftDiQbXANAZtlEF3eX8JREyL7qEx00X4WXPyNTxkkJh0CFMC8hDEHSDxVvX2zQmZgCEpGsMe3VsSiKPK6FofhjgkWfuF2PfUrTBO6WL6cGxOucuvYtdXJOLWvjUcDEmrkdbTJiqPILumVawfs3KAAzo7KJsb2AN8n1WM2oSVI7oH3hsAbEl%2Fx7ljANBC%2F%2FJ%2Fmbifho5i8lqGG3GSF%2BT%2B26gKIwXymw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200722T175345Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYWMRXLSUN%2F20200722%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=e42d4d7efd46168a90cb275debe065cc559bfa0f82d9988c83c0538944adcd41&hash=219169c646b6c74c71403124b515e9b4b61ac091d0fff0c241183bb2746fe852&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021869381903343&tid=spdf-6803cfbf-d67b-49bf-b72b-5e96ece41f05&sid=76b8711923cd114cdc8aa9c4d50e1ff58851gxrqb&type=client).

Another result which may be of interest -regarding your fourth question- is that:

> If the semigroup $k\Lambda$ has the same quotient field with $k[t]$, then $D(K)$ is Morita equivalent to $A_1$.

Here $K$ stands for certain subalgebras of $k[t]$ and $D(K)$ for the ring of differential operators on $K$. This is shown in: [Some rings of differential operators which are Morita equivalent to $A_1$, Ian Musson, Proc. of the Am. Math. Soc., 98, 1, 1986](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-098-01/S0002-9939-1986-0848868-1/S0002-9939-1986-0848868-1.pdf)

Finally, if you are interested in examples involving smash products with finite group algebras, i do not have some readily available but i think it is natural to look for such in the graded version of Morita equivalence.

I hope these are of some interest to the OP. Sorry in advance if these are too old and you are already aware of them.

**P.S.:** One more thing which might be of some interest with respect to the second question: The article [Rings graded equivalent to the Weyl algebra, J. of Alg., vol. 321, 2, 2009](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002186930800519X), generalizes some results of Y. Berest, G. Wilson and Stafford, in the setting of graded module categories. (also i think this article is the first -although i am not sure- which introduces the terminology "*graded Morita equivalence*")

Comment: I already knew these papers, but anyhow thanks for reminding me of them! Hopefully I can check if they lead to new developments related to the fourth question!